# Use Google Assistant Action to trigger a phone call from my number

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to build a Google Assistant Action that dials a phone number (using my device and my phone number) and once the call is connected interact using Dialogflow's voice synthesis to interact for a few minutes before connecting me.

Is there an option to do this inside the Actions SDK?

**The desired behavior** is to do this the same way Assistant does when I say "Hey Google call Mom". (This might be a North America only feature at the moment) Basically, it connects the call via my Google account phone number so caller ID looks like it's from me via either a mobile device or smart speaker.

Dialogflow appears to have a [beta telephony](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/telephony) option that might be a usable workaround, but it's a handoff, not the call coming from me.

Alternately is there a service like Twilio for voice calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is not currently available with Actions on Google.

The Dialogflow outbound telephony feature is only to transfer calls that have come in through the telephony feature. It does not work with the Assistant.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Any alternatives or am I stuck with manually dialing phone numbers in 2019?